# Don't print in Log when select Spinner

Tags: android, spinner, android-spinner

I need to use Spinner in my Android Application. I must do some operation when the spinner is selected.For example I would print in Log when I select the spinner:

```
Spinner regione=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.regione);

        regione.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Log.i("in", "in");
                if(id==R.id.regione){
                    Log.i("ext", "exit");

                }
            }
```

But when I control my Console I don't see the worlds "in" or "exit". Anyone can help me?

Comment: Have you tried setting a breakpoint in there or a Toast?

Comment: Alternatively, you can use `System.out.println` if `Log.d` is causing trouble

Comment: Try setting a toast. Atleast it will let you know whether it's going inside Listener code. Or use System.out.print to show messge on Logcat

Comment: When you say "selecting the spinner" are you actually selecting a spinner item or just tapping the spinner to show the items?